# Keyboard in loop printing timestamp

Tags: keyboards

I have a problem with keyborad of my laptop.
When I use text editor and I press specific keys (5,6 ...) the editor goes crazy and enters the loop printing the actual timestamp, until I hit enter.
If I use browser, this keys reset the search bar, so it has a different effect.
I formatted all data and updated the bios, but issue persist.
I have a HP 14-cb107nl.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to ask this on Super User SE, as it is off-topic here. And OS needs to be specified. If you have access to an external keyboard, that's a logical first step.

Comment: I use windows 10. II've already tried with external keyboard and it work fine

Comment: What is "the actual timestamp" text?

Comment: for example, when I press 5 it prints in a loop: 5 2021/09/08 16:23:00 2021/09/08 16:23:00 2021/09/08 16:23:00 2021/09/08 16:23:00 .....

Comment: Seems like a hardware problem of some kind, but probably not the keyboard itself. Just to confirm Windows is not involved somehow, you could boot to an Ubuntu Live CD (use the "Try it" selection) and see if the problem is still there. See [Try Ubuntu before you install it](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started)

Comment: Hi, I've already tried with ubuntu live and there is no problem. It works properly with ubuntu live

Comment: Then it must be a Windows 10 problem somehow. Maybe internal keyboard driver or such, but I haven't seen such a problem before.

Comment: This isn't really a 'hardware recommendation', it's a tech support question, better suited to https://superuser.com/